# How to avoid all records which has a duplicate present and get only unique records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hy mates,

I have a database table which looks like this:

```
uniqueId,asin,rank
1,abc,1
2,xyz,2
3,abc,1
4,xyz,2
5,opq,3
```

As you can see that the asin's (abc and xyz) were repeated. So I would like my query to avoid them completey and return me only (opq).

Best Regards

Usama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
select *
from yourtable a
where 1 = (
  select count(*)
  from yourtable
  where a.asin = asin
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2b525/1)

Answer (score 0):

`not exists` should have the best performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.asin = t.asin and t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(asin, id)`.